# Arabic text in managed bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, arabic

In my application I use Spring, JPA Hibernate, JSF
the problem is when I write an Arabic text and find it in manged Bean like (ÙØ§Ø¨ÙÙÙ)
I use Tomcat v 7.0 Server

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Form is

```
<h:form dir="rtl" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
```

before Head

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

In head of page.

```
<f:view locale="TR" encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

I use `@Named` in managed bean `@MangedBean` and `@Component` are not right too.

MySQL database are good I read from it Arabic text correctly.

In constructor,

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

try {
    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please any hint to take a valid Arabic text. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to understand your exact problem. You mean, when you do `System.out.println(input)` inside managed bean, then you're seeing Mojibake instead of Arabic in the server log? What if you ignore that step and just proceed to save the input in the database, is it then still Mojibake or is it proper Arabic over there in the database?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to start every single word with a capital. It makes your text only harder to read. Capitalization is only necessary at start of sentences and for names like "JSF", "Hibernate", etc. Try spending a bit more time reading English articles and finding/following the same patterns.

Comment: ok i will read English articles :D

Comment: when i save this code to database still Mojibake Not be arabic

Comment: Okay. Does this also happen when you save a hardcoded string value in a Java class instead of taking user input from a JSF form? Then we can tell apart if the problem is in frontend (the JSF side) or in backend (the JPA side).

Comment: when i take it from input user

Comment: Okay. You've there a Spring character encoding filter. It should already do its job and you shouldn't have the need to manually call `setCharacterEncoding()` in constructor. Please remove them in constructor and do a `System.out.println(request.getCharacterEncoding())`. What do you see printed?

Comment: UTF-8
but character still ÙÙÙÙ

Comment: Does it say `UTF-8` or `utf-8`? The correct spelling is `UTF-8` and you should also set that in `web.xml`.

Comment: UTF-8 upper case Letter

Comment: Okay. Do you have more filters in your web application?

Comment: No this is my only filter

Comment: Well, then I'm not seeing any probable causes. Can you please reconfirm that you are seeing proper characters in database when you use a hardcoded string value instead of taking user input? You have nowhere explicitly confirmed that, you only said that you're taking user input.

Comment: hardcoded string value is Ok insert right in DB

Comment: I'm not seeing any other probable causes based on the information provided so far. So, unless there's a miscommunication, your problem remains a mystery.

Comment: thanks :D but there is no miscommunication :D

Comment: The problem is on server side check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922522/how-do-i-properly-include-the-org-apache-catalina-filters-setcharacterencodingf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem when i used tomcat encoding filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignore</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Conversation</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Conversation</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Spring encoding filter does the same as Tomcat encoding filter. The real cause is still elsewhere.

Comment: this work with me but spring encoding filter doesn't work