# How do I properly include the "org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter" filter in my Maven project?

Tags: maven, tomcat, utf-8, jboss, servlet-filters

I’m using Maven 3.3 with JBoss 7.1.3.Final (Java 6).  I want to include a filter in my web app so that all incoming request data will be encoded as UTF-8.  SO I added this to my web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and this Maven dependency …

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

but upon deploying my application, I get the below error …

```
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter from [Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

What dependency do I need to include so that my application will deploy successfully?

Comment: You claim that you're using JBoss 7.1.3, but your error message is from the undertow module which did not appear until WildFly 8.x. @BalusC: I think all of the JBossAS versions (excluding WildFly based JBoss EAPs) used Tomcat as the basis for it's web container; they moved to undertow around the time that they changed the name to WildFly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question doesn't make sense in first place.

1. [That filter is part of Tomcat server](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#Set_Character_Encoding_Filter), not JBoss server.
2. That Maven dependency basically installs Tomcat's engine in the webapp. This would only conflict with server's own Tomcat engine in case you're actually using JBoss AS.
3. You said you're using JBoss AS, but that error message is specific to JBoss WildFly.

I'll assume that you're indeed targeting JBoss WildFly and thus not Apache Tomcat nor JBoss AS. The correct approach to enable UTF-8 in JBoss WildFly is to edit its `/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` to change the following line:

```
<servlet-container name="default">
```

to add the `default-encoding` attribute:

```
<servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">
```

In case you're *actually* using JBoss AS 7.x and that error was merely uncarefully copypasted from a test environment, the correct approach to enable UTF-8 in JBoss AS 7.x (and thus not 6.x or lower!) is to edit its  `/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` to add the following entry between the `<extensions>` and `<management>` entries:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
</system-properties>
```

In case you're not allowed to manipulate the server configuration and/or want to keep the webapp as much as possible portable across different servers, then just create that filter yourself. Below are the essential lines:

```java
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Just drop that class anywhere in your webapp (not in JAR) and it'll automatically do its job.