# send arabic data in spring mvc form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, encode

i have a spring form where i need to send some data in arabic so 
i set the page encoding and the content type to UTF-8 like this :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

when i display the data in the controller i get something like this `?¨???¦?³?±???§` 
i'm using spring 4 along with spring security, i don't know if this can be be the cause, but can it be the csrf added by spring security ?
thanks in advance

Comment: please check this prior solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: i checked that solution, but i got the opposite of this issue as displaying characters is fine but when i send a post request that holds some arabic data it is not encoded correctly .

Comment: I have found such solutions that seem to be working for non-English languages and arabic for a encoding "ISO-8859-6". Can you check these posts whether they may help? http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=28944&message_id=201635 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33934752/1958683